# Check whether type is char or wchar_t in compile time

Tags: c++

I want to copy an array (either char* or wchar_t*) and I am having the following function:

```
template<typename T>
T* doStuff(const T* str)
{
    T* newArr;
    if( typeid(str).name() == typeid(const wchar_t*).name())
    {
        newArr = wcsdup(str);
    }
    else if (typeid(str).name() == typeid(const char*).name())
    {
        newArr = strdup(str);
    }
    // ...do some more
}
```

The problem is that when I am calling the function first with char* argument and then with wchar_t argument I am getting a compile time error (error: no matching function for call to 'wcsdup' AND error: no matching function for call to 'strdup').

Is there a way to check in compile time whether my template is either char* or wchar_t*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use overload:

```
wchar_t* my_dup(const wchar_t* str) { return wcsdup(str); }
char* my_dup(const char* str) { return strdup(str); }

template<typename T>
T* doStuff(const T* str)
{
    T* newArr = my_dup(str);
    // ...do some more
}
```

And to answer to your question, you may use `std::is_same` to check at compile time the type of `T`

```
std::is_same<wchar_t, T>::value
```